# findMany works but deleteMany doesn't

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, prisma

I have a simple *Note* table and a *Tag* table with an implicit many-to-many relation.

```
model Tag {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  tag   String @unique
  notes Note[]
}

model Note {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  note  String @unique
  tags  Tags[]
  ...
}
```

When I delete a note I want to delete the tags which was only in that note. I wrote this:

```
await prisma.tag.deleteMany({
    where: {
      notes: { none: { tags: { some: { tag: { in: tags } } } } }, // tags: string[] coming from deleted note
    },
  });
```

but it gives me the error:

```
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Server(ServerError { code: 1093, message: "You can't specify target table 'Tags' for update in FROM clause", state: "HY000" })) })
```

but when I change it to findMany it finds them without any problem. What is the problem?

Currently I'm running another deleteMany on the data from findMany. I've read that in pure SQL you can wrap it in another SELECT but is there anything I can do in prisma?

Comment: Share you schema please, at least tag and notes 

Comment: And the code for the delete note

Comment: @Pompedup schema is just a simple implicit mn relation but I added it to the question. And delete note is ```prisma.note.delete({where: {id}})```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot to find this.

Your problem is coming from mysql, I try with postgresql and I couldn't reproduce it.

But by chance, there is a solution.

Your new prisma query looks like:

```js
await prisma.tag.deleteMany({
  where: {
    // Search tag with no notes
    notes: { none: {} },
    // and in your list
    tag: { in: tags }
  },
});
```

**EDIT**
In reality, if you don't want any tags that are not linked to a note you can do only

```js
await prisma.tag.deleteMany({
  where: {
    notes: { none: {} },
  },
});
```

because it will search every tags with no notes linked to. The only thing is that it will check for all your tags in the `Tag` table so it won't be really efficient

**To explain a little more `notes: { none: {} }`**

Using mocked tables

`Relationship Note / Tag` table:

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║ node_id ║ tag_id ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║ Note1   ║ Tag1   ║
║ Note1   ║ Tag2   ║
║ Note2   ║ Tag2   ║
║ Note3   ║ Tag3   ║
║ Note4   ║        ║
║ Note5   ║        ║
║         ║ Tag4   ║
║         ║ Tag5   ║
║         ║ Tag6   ║
║         ║ Tag7   ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

`Note` table

```
╔═══════╦══════╗
║  id   ║ note ║
╠═══════╬══════╣
║ Note1 ║ a    ║
║ Note2 ║ b    ║
║ Note3 ║ c    ║
║ Note4 ║ d    ║
║ Note5 ║ e    ║
╚═══════╩══════╝
```

**First case**

When you add the filter `notes: { none: {} }`, you ask Prisma to find every tags that have none notes, so no relation in the `Relationship Note / Tag` table

So with a find many with this filter:

```js
const tags = await prisma.tag.findMany({
  where: {
    notes: { none: {} },
  },
});
```

`tags` will contain the tags for ids `Tag4`, `Tag5`,`Tag6` and `Tag7` because they are not related to any note

**Second case**

When you do `notes: { none: { note: 'a' } }` you ask Prisma to find any tags that have none notes with `note` value = `a`

So with a find many with this filter:

```js
const tags = await prisma.tag.findMany({
  where: {
    notes: { none: { note: 'a' } },
  },
});
```

`tags` will contain all tags except `Tag1` and `Tag2` that are related to `Note1` with `note` value = `a`

**END EDIT**

**FYI**
Here, you weren't doing what you thought

`notes: { none: { tags: { some: { tag: tags } } } }`

You ask to search `tags` where notes doesn't have `tags` in tags

So if you had these relations

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║ node_id ║ tag_id ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║ Note1   ║ Tag1   ║
║ Note1   ║ Tag2   ║
║ Note2   ║ Tag3   ║
║ Note3   ║ Tag3   ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

And you delete `Note3` and then search for `Tag3` with this query, Tag3 linked to Note2 does have some `Tag3`, so not deleted, but Tag2 doesn't have some notes with some `Tag3`, so it is deleted, same for `Tag1`

Comment: Thank you. `notes: { none: { tags: { some: { tag: { in: tags } } } } }`
I tested this with 2-3 notes and it worked but when I just tried it with your example, Tag3 was the only one not deleted!
`notes: { none: {} }`
Since the tags belong to notes I forgot that I can check if the tag doesn't have any notes. this works. But how? Usually inside the `none` you put a condition to check. So this would mean none of the notes are? Are what? {}?

Comment: It can work if one of your tags where linked to every notes I guess
You can read the edit part. Is it good to you?

Comment: Yes It's all good. I get it now. Thank you.